# Estimate an error bound for an estimate

Tags: prediction, error, prediction-interval

I have two datasets regarding historical data (say, quarterly revenues for companies over time). The first is the actual results of this data and the other is available estimates for these results prior to their release.

The datasets have the same shape:

```
company year quarter revenue
      1    1       1      10
      1    1       2      11
      1    1       3      12
      1    1       4      13
      2    1       1      14
[...]
```

I am trying to use this historical data to evaluate the "expected error" for future estimates. However, I'm unsure as to which metric is appropriate to use in this case.

I can obviously join the datasets and calculate the error of each estimate as a percentage:

```
company year quarter revError
      1    1       1     0.07
      1    1       2    -0.02
      1    1       3    -0.10
      1    1       4     0.04
      2    1       1     0.01
[...]
```

I can then collect the average error and the error's standard deviation per company. As I understand it, this would give me two datapoints:

- the average would tell me whether there's bias in the estimates, maybe whoever developed the estimates is excessively optimistic about the company.
- the standard deviation would tell me the breadth of the errors. Companies with good estimates (very close to the actual result) will have small standard deviations and those with unreliable estimates will have larger standard deviations.

Is that it? Just calculate that and then apply it to future estimates as "expected revenue of $100 \pm 3\%$" (if 3% is $2\sigma$ for a 95% confidence interval)? And if the average error indicates a significant bias (i.e. estimates are usually 20% above reality), can I adjust my historical estimates accordingly (such that the bias is synthetically eliminated), recalculate the standard deviation and then use the adjusted SD with my future (adjusted) estimates?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give a confidence margin on the estimates, your approach of estimating the standard deviation of the errors, $\sigma$, and then giving a confidence interval of $2\sigma$ is sound; assuming that the errors are well described by a Gaussian distribution this interval would represent 95% confidence interval.

However, in general, the predictive performance of any algorithm/model that learn from a limited sample of data is fundamentally bounded by the sum of two error terms: [bias and variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff) (see also [this link](http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html) for a nice introduction). Having the whole history of estimates and true values allows quantifying the performance of the estimates (or predictions) both in terms of their bias (the first datapoint that you mention) and variance. Thus you could, as you say, estimate the bias and correct future estimates by subtracting it. If it is safe to assume that the bias is a static quantity (i.e. it does not change over time) this is pretty much the best you can do. 
However, if it makes sense to assume that the bias and variance of the estimates changes gradually over time (for example because the analysts of each company might do some adjustment to the models they use to predict future revenue?), then you might obtain better estimates of the current bias and variance using a sequential algorithm such as a Kalman filter (for example modelling changes in bias and variance over time with a random walk). [*Disclaimer: I don't work with this type of data and I am note sure of what type of assumption are made when modelling companies' revenues. Perhaps there is a better way to model this than assuming a random walk and Gaussian variability.*]

Note also that having a bias is not necessarily a bad thing, at least from a statistical point of view. Many estimators deliberately introduce in the estimates a small, acceptable amount of bias to reduce the variance (see for example [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) estimators such as LASSO or Ridge regression). In fact you could classify different companies based on their bias-variance trade-off; e.g. what is the proportion of total error that due to the bias vs that due to the variance? Do companies that have greater bias achieve smaller or larger overall error?. I suspect that in this case the *optimal* tradeoff between bias and variance - the one that minimize the expected error of the predicted revenues - likely depends on the 'volatility' of the revenue of that company (are the stable across quarters, or fluctuate a lot over time?).

Finally, perhaps the direction of the error might also affect its valence for the company? For example, under-estimating slightly the revenues might be "better" than eventually overestimating (and over-spending)? I am not sure if that is relevant here, but in that case it might be useful to quantify the performance of the estimators according to an asymmetrical cost function. Note sure if that's interesting/useful, in case let me know and I can expand on this.